# What is the XML equivalent of this Spring Configure? Java to XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, oauth

I am trying to understand the following configure from some code on `Github` which implements `OAuth2`; the original source can be found [here](https://github.com/lorenzodee/spring-security-oauth2-google). I am getting tripped up as I use `XML` for this type of configuration in my own application and I do not know the equivalent, specifically for the add filter before and after portion. While there is a plethora of information online including of course the `XML` definitions, navigating this has proven a source of great frustration. Would some kind soul show me the `XML` equivalent for this configure or point me to a good point of reference for further study?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        /* No need for form-based login or basic authentication
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("...")
                .loginProcessingUrl("...")
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
         */
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(
                oauth2ClientContextFilter,
                ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(
                oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
            .anonymous()
            // anonymous login must be disabled,
            // otherwise an anonymous authentication will be created,
            // and the UserRedirectRequiredException will not be thrown,
            // and the user will not be redirected to the authorization server
                .disable();
}
```

An XML equivalent (my starting point):

```
<http>
    <oauth2-login
        login-page="/login" 
    />
    <oauth2-client/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
</http>
```